# Rails: how to save form data after posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use `form_for :model` the data is saved when I submit the form.

However when I use `form_tag`, the data is lost after the form is processed.

I need to use `form_tag` because I have two models in one form.

Is there a way to save form data with `form_tag`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making two incorrect assumptions in your question. First, `form_tag` is not necessary or even recommended for multiple-model forms; Second, `form_tag` doesn't do anything fundamentally different from `form_for`, you are most likely not formatting the field names correctly for your controller.

In order to create a form with nested models, you need to use the `fields_for` helper in conjunction with `form_for`. The relationship needs to be defined first in the model with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Since you have not given us any information about your models, I will give you a made-up example:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

This tells ActiveRecord that the Person model can accept attributes for Address, and will pass along the attributes to the correct model to be created.

```
<% form_for :person do |p| %>
  <% p.fields_for :address do |a| %>
    use the a form builder to create
    fields for the address model here
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

chaining the `fields_for` helper from the `p` form builder lets the helpers generate attributes in the correct format.

More information: [Nested Model Forms](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms)

Comment: Thank you for this great detailed answer. I learned a lot, and I fixed everything.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much the same way as before except you'll need to build the params. You can look at your log to see how params are being sent.

eg.

```
def create
  @silly_hat = SillyHat.new( :name => params[:name], :size => params[:size], :colour => params[:colour] )
  if @silly_hat.save
    ...
```

Comment: So how should my form look like?  I'm using password_field_tag :password and it doesn't work.